# H2O XGBoost crashing from local server dying or hanging(?)

Tags: xgboost, h2o

It's going to take some work for me to build a smaller test case PLUS I have to get permission to release the data (after I anonymize it), but H2O crashes on me consistently with this data and parameters.  (It usually succeeds with different combinations of feature inputs and parameters but seems to fail always with features and parameters below).

The data has 12847393 rows (which may be the provoking the problem?)

This is the ugly stack crawl I got.  (It seems reproducible.)

Filed as bug:  https://0xdata.atlassian.net/projects/PUBDEV/issues/PUBDEV-7321

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ConnectionResetError                      Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py in urlopen(self, method, url, body, headers, retries, redirect, assert_same_host, timeout, pool_timeout, release_conn, chunked, body_pos, **response_kw)
    599                                                   body=body, headers=headers,
--> 600                                                   chunked=chunked)
    601 

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py in _make_request(self, conn, method, url, timeout, chunked, **httplib_request_kw)
    383                     # otherwise it looks like a programming error was the cause.
--> 384                     six.raise_from(e, None)
    385         except (SocketTimeout, BaseSSLError, SocketError) as e:

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/urllib3/packages/six.py in raise_from(value, from_value)

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py in _make_request(self, conn, method, url, timeout, chunked, **httplib_request_kw)
    379                 try:
--> 380                     httplib_response = conn.getresponse()
    381                 except Exception as e:

/usr/lib/python3.6/http/client.py in getresponse(self)
   1345             try:
-> 1346                 response.begin()
   1347             except ConnectionError:

/usr/lib/python3.6/http/client.py in begin(self)
    306         while True:
--> 307             version, status, reason = self._read_status()
    308             if status != CONTINUE:

/usr/lib/python3.6/http/client.py in _read_status(self)
    267     def _read_status(self):
--> 268         line = str(self.fp.readline(_MAXLINE + 1), "iso-8859-1")
    269         if len(line) > _MAXLINE:

/usr/lib/python3.6/socket.py in readinto(self, b)
    585             try:
--> 586                 return self._sock.recv_into(b)
    587             except timeout:

ConnectionResetError: [Errno 104] Connection reset by peer

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

ProtocolError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/requests/adapters.py in send(self, request, stream, timeout, verify, cert, proxies)
    448                     retries=self.max_retries,
--> 449                     timeout=timeout
    450                 )

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py in urlopen(self, method, url, body, headers, retries, redirect, assert_same_host, timeout, pool_timeout, release_conn, chunked, body_pos, **response_kw)
    637             retries = retries.increment(method, url, error=e, _pool=self,
--> 638                                         _stacktrace=sys.exc_info()[2])
    639             retries.sleep()

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/urllib3/util/retry.py in increment(self, method, url, response, error, _pool, _stacktrace)
    366             if read is False or not self._is_method_retryable(method):
--> 367                 raise six.reraise(type(error), error, _stacktrace)
    368             elif read is not None:

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/urllib3/packages/six.py in reraise(tp, value, tb)
    684         if value.__traceback__ is not tb:
--> 685             raise value.with_traceback(tb)
    686         raise value

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py in urlopen(self, method, url, body, headers, retries, redirect, assert_same_host, timeout, pool_timeout, release_conn, chunked, body_pos, **response_kw)
    599                                                   body=body, headers=headers,
--> 600                                                   chunked=chunked)
    601 

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py in _make_request(self, conn, method, url, timeout, chunked, **httplib_request_kw)
    383                     # otherwise it looks like a programming error was the cause.
--> 384                     six.raise_from(e, None)
    385         except (SocketTimeout, BaseSSLError, SocketError) as e:

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/urllib3/packages/six.py in raise_from(value, from_value)

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py in _make_request(self, conn, method, url, timeout, chunked, **httplib_request_kw)
    379                 try:
--> 380                     httplib_response = conn.getresponse()
    381                 except Exception as e:

/usr/lib/python3.6/http/client.py in getresponse(self)
   1345             try:
-> 1346                 response.begin()
   1347             except ConnectionError:

/usr/lib/python3.6/http/client.py in begin(self)
    306         while True:
--> 307             version, status, reason = self._read_status()
    308             if status != CONTINUE:

/usr/lib/python3.6/http/client.py in _read_status(self)
    267     def _read_status(self):
--> 268         line = str(self.fp.readline(_MAXLINE + 1), "iso-8859-1")
    269         if len(line) > _MAXLINE:

/usr/lib/python3.6/socket.py in readinto(self, b)
    585             try:
--> 586                 return self._sock.recv_into(b)
    587             except timeout:

ProtocolError: ('Connection aborted.', ConnectionResetError(104, 'Connection reset by peer'))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

ConnectionError                           Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/h2o/backend/connection.py in request(self, endpoint, data, json, filename, save_to)
    473                                     headers=headers, timeout=self._timeout, stream=stream,
--> 474                                     auth=self._auth, verify=verify, proxies=self._proxies)
    475             if isinstance(save_to, types.FunctionType):

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/requests/api.py in request(method, url, **kwargs)
     59     with sessions.Session() as session:
---> 60         return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
     61 

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/requests/sessions.py in request(self, method, url, params, data, headers, cookies, files, auth, timeout, allow_redirects, proxies, hooks, stream, verify, cert, json)
    532         send_kwargs.update(settings)
--> 533         resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
    534 

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/requests/sessions.py in send(self, request, **kwargs)
    645         # Send the request
--> 646         r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
    647 

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/requests/adapters.py in send(self, request, stream, timeout, verify, cert, proxies)
    497         except (ProtocolError, socket.error) as err:
--> 498             raise ConnectionError(err, request=request)
    499 

ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', ConnectionResetError(104, 'Connection reset by peer'))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

H2OConnectionError                        Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-56b68eefa416> in <module>
     87 start_time = time.time()
     88 model  = H2OXGBoostEstimator(**param)
---> 89 model.train(x=x, y="y", training_frame=hdf6)
     90 elapsed_time = time.time() - start_time

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/h2o/estimators/estimator_base.py in train(self, x, y, training_frame, offset_column, fold_column, weights_column, validation_frame, max_runtime_secs, ignored_columns, model_id, verbose)
    110         self._train(x=x, y=y, training_frame=training_frame, offset_column=offset_column, fold_column=fold_column,
    111                     weights_column=weights_column, validation_frame=validation_frame, max_runtime_secs=max_runtime_secs,
--> 112                     ignored_columns=ignored_columns, model_id=model_id, verbose=verbose)
    113 
    114 

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/h2o/estimators/estimator_base.py in _train(self, x, y, training_frame, offset_column, fold_column, weights_column, validation_frame, max_runtime_secs, ignored_columns, model_id, verbose, extend_parms_fn)
    263             return
    264 
--> 265         model.poll(poll_updates=self._print_model_scoring_history if verbose else None)
    266         model_json = h2o.api("GET /%d/Models/%s" % (rest_ver, model.dest_key))["models"][0]
    267         self._resolve_model(model.dest_key, model_json)

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/h2o/job.py in poll(self, poll_updates)
     58                 pb.execute(self._refresh_job_status, print_verbose_info=ft.partial(poll_updates, self))
     59             else:
---> 60                 pb.execute(self._refresh_job_status)
     61         except StopIteration as e:
     62             if str(e) == "cancelled":

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/h2o/utils/progressbar.py in execute(self, progress_fn, print_verbose_info)
    169                 # Query the progress level, but only if it's time already
    170                 if self._next_poll_time <= now:
--> 171                     res = progress_fn()  # may raise StopIteration
    172                     assert_is_type(res, (numeric, numeric), numeric)
    173                     if not isinstance(res, tuple):

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/h2o/job.py in _refresh_job_status(self)
     96     def _refresh_job_status(self):
     97         if self._poll_count <= 0: raise StopIteration("")
---> 98         jobs = h2o.api("GET /3/Jobs/%s" % self.job_key)
     99         self.job = jobs["jobs"][0] if "jobs" in jobs else jobs["job"][0]
    100         self.status = self.job["status"]

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/h2o/h2o.py in api(endpoint, data, json, filename, save_to)
    121     # type checks are performed in H2OConnection class
    122     _check_connection()
--> 123     return h2oconn.request(endpoint, data=data, json=json, filename=filename, save_to=save_to)
    124 
    125 

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/h2o/backend/connection.py in request(self, endpoint, data, json, filename, save_to)
    481             if self._local_server and not self._local_server.is_running():
    482                 self._log_end_exception("Local server has died.")
--> 483                 raise H2OConnectionError("Local server has died unexpectedly. RIP.")
    484             else:
    485                 self._log_end_exception(e)

H2OConnectionError: Local server has died unexpectedly. RIP.
```

Parameters passed:

```
param = {
      "ntrees" : 15
    , "min_rows" : 5
    , "max_depth" : 5
    , "learn_rate" : 0.02
    , "sample_rate" : 0.7
    , "col_sample_rate_per_tree" : 0.9
    , "seed": 42
    , "score_tree_interval": 100
}
```

There were 14 input columns, of which 5 were categorical features.

I initialized H2O like this:

```
h2o.init(
    strict_version_check=False,
#    nthreads=1,   # Crashes either with 1 or 4 threads.
    log_dir="/tmp/clem-h2o/",
    log_level='TRACE'
)



Checking whether there is an H2O instance running at http://localhost:54321 ..... not found.
Attempting to start a local H2O server...
  Java Version: openjdk version "1.8.0_242"; OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_242-8u242-b08-0ubuntu3~18.04-b08); OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.242-b08, mixed mode)
  Starting server from /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/h2o/backend/bin/h2o.jar
  Ice root: /tmp/tmpkeo9aau1
  JVM stdout: /tmp/tmpkeo9aau1/h2o_unknownUser_started_from_python.out
  JVM stderr: /tmp/tmpkeo9aau1/h2o_unknownUser_started_from_python.err
  Server is running at http://127.0.0.1:54321
Connecting to H2O server at http://127.0.0.1:54321 ... successful.
H2O cluster uptime: 01 secs
H2O cluster timezone:   Etc/UTC
H2O data parsing timezone:  UTC
H2O cluster version:    3.28.0.3
H2O cluster version age:    14 days, 3 hours and 57 minutes
H2O cluster name:   H2O_from_python_unknownUser_xuimzh
H2O cluster total nodes:    1
H2O cluster free memory:    4.445 Gb
H2O cluster total cores:    4
H2O cluster allowed cores:  4
H2O cluster status: accepting new members, healthy
H2O connection url: http://127.0.0.1:54321
H2O connection proxy:   {'http': None, 'https': None}
H2O internal security:  False
H2O API Extensions: Amazon S3, XGBoost, Algos, AutoML, Core V3, TargetEncoder, Core V4
Python version: 3.6.9 final
```

Unfortunately, the warning, error and fatal log files are empty.  I can't release the other log files until I anonymize the feature names...

I don't know if there are some other debugging switches that could help diagnose the problem.

This is the version info:

```
H2O Version:  3.28.0.3
Python 3.6.9
Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS
```